# "Expected function body after function declarator " compiled using GCC in Terminal

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, gcc-4.2

I am trying to compile following program using GCC in terminal

```
//
//  fileCopy.c
//  
//
//  Created by Saurabh Saini on 14/02/18.
//
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

int c;
c = getchar();

if(c!=EOF){
    putchar(c);
    c = getchar();
}
return 0;
}
```

getting the following error [image]

I need to understand what is

```
<U+0010>
```

Comment: You have a rogue character, it's even visible in the question. It's that cross over there...

Comment: Please do not post screen-shots. Better copypaste console output into your question.

Comment: Okay i will keep in mind from next time.Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<U+0010>` is here indicating that: *Unicode character with value 0x10(hexadecimal; 16 in decimal)*.

`<U+0010>` is called `DATA LINK ESCAPE(DLE)`

The error is due to this character. Since `<U+0010>` is a *control character* hence it is not being ignored by `gcc` compiler(*whitespace* charecters are ignored by `gcc` compiler) so, it is creating compilation error. Remove this character from your source file and it will solve the problem.

**Note:** `<U+0010>` is non printable character so you can't see it. You need to use some `hex-editor` editor. You can use `vim` editor. See [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2232/how-can-i-use-vim-as-a-hex-editor) and [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/343/how-to-edit-binary-files-with-vim) about how to use it.

Comment: Also known as control-P.